# Number prime with c++, what is wrong with the code and how to optimize?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure this problem http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/problems/view/1032, where I need to find the prime numbers between 1 to 3501 the fastest way, since the time limit may not exceed 1 second.

The way I'm calculating these prime numbers is to check if they are prime until their square root, then eliminating the multiple of the first prime numbers [2, 3, 5, 7] to improve the performance of the algorithm. Yet, the time exceeds.

My code (takes 1.560s as the internal testing of the submission system)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

set<int> circ;
set<int> primes;

/* Calculate List Primes */ 
void n_prime(int qtd){
    int a, flag=1, l_prime = 1;
    float n;
    for(int i=0;i<qtd;i++){
        switch (l_prime){
            case 1:
                l_prime = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                l_prime = 3;
                break;
            default:
                while(1){
                    flag=1;
                    l_prime+=2;
                    if(l_prime>7)
                    while(l_prime%2==0||l_prime%3==0||l_prime%5==0||l_prime%7==0) l_prime++;
                    n=sqrt(l_prime);
                    for(a=2;a<=n;a++){
                        if(l_prime%a==0){
                            flag=0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag) break;
                }
        }
        primes.insert(l_prime);
    }
}

/* Initialize set with live's */ 
void init_circ(int t){
    circ.clear();
    for(int a=0;a<t;a++){
        circ.insert(a+1);
    }
}

/* Show last live*/
void show_last(){
    for(set<int>::iterator it=circ.begin(); it!=circ.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << "\n";
}

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    clock_t c1, c2;
    c1 = clock();
    n_prime(3501);
    while(scanf("%d", &n)&&n!=0){
        init_circ(n);
        int idx=0, l_prime,count = 0;
        set<int>::iterator it;
        set<int>::iterator np;
        np=primes.begin();
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            l_prime=*np;
            *np++;
            idx = (idx+l_prime-1) % circ.size();
            it = circ.begin();
            advance(it, idx);
            circ.erase(it);
        }
        show_last();
    }
    c2 = clock();
    printf("\n\nTime: %.3lf", (double)(c2-c1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use the [sieve of eratosthenes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921456/sieve-of-eratosthenes)

Comment: Also consider the [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin), which is an optimized version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes. But for your small number range, it's quite likely the speed difference is only trivial.

Comment: BTW if you like problems like this you should really try [project euler](http://projecteuler.net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is the [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), here's my implementation:

```
//return the seive of erstothenes
std::vector<int> generate_seive(const ulong & max) {
    std::vector<int> seive{2};
    std::vector<bool> not_prime(max+1);
    ulong current_prime = seive.back();
    bool done = false;
    while(!done){ 
        for (int i = 2; i * current_prime <= max;i++) {
            not_prime[i*current_prime]=true;
        }
        for (int j = current_prime+1;true;j++) {
            if (not_prime[j] == false) {
                if( j >= max) {
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    seive.push_back(j);
                    current_prime = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return seive;
}
```

Generates all the prime numbers under max, BTW these are the times for my sieve and 3501 as the max number.

```
real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Comment: By the way, you can optimize your code even further if you change the starting value for i to current_prime. The key observation for this change is that you are trying to compose factors of the type `i * current_prime` where `i < current_prime`, so i will have a prime factor p, which is less than current_prime, and thus the number `i * current_prime` will be marked as composite on the mark iteration for the prime p (which we had found earlier). However, you should be aware for an int overflow at the expression `i * current_prime <= max`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better algorithm for finding primes. Have you heard about [Eratosthenes and his sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)?

Also, you are using tons of STL (i.e. the set<>) as well as remainder operations in your code. This is simply killing the speed of your program.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the STL, in most cases using it will greatly improve your code

Comment: what do you mean by "module operations"?

Comment: Do you know what [beautiful] structure lies behind set<>? The problem here is that it is completely irrelevant -- you can use a simple array. And it is a whole other topic whether STL improves your code. Certainly it helps you a lot. However, if you want the fastest solution, it is better to implement everything yourself.

Comment: @DavidBrown I meant remainder (or modulus) operations. Thanks, I'll correct it.

Comment: @yasen I wasn't arguing that you should use a set, but stl data structures generally do not slow down your code by any significant amount, any c++ expert will tell you to always prefer something from the standard library over a c style array

Comment: @yasen: note that using the standard library allows the compiler to use certain intrinsics that it otherwise might not be able to if you "implement everything yourself."

Comment: @yasen for an example use c-style arrays with my implementation of the sieve and see if it runs faster than mine

Comment: @aaronman It depends on the input. For 3500 there won't be any *huge* difference.

Comment: @yasen well obviously, if your feeling bold write it and test it for 10000000

Comment: @aaronman For 10M your code is around 1.5 times faster than mine (300 ms vs. 470 ms). For 100M my code is around 1 sec faster than yours (~6 s vs. ~5 s). However, if I add the optimization I mentioned (as a comment on your accepted answer) and change the type if `i` to `long long`, then your code is around 0.5 s faster than mine :) So STL isn't that bad after all.

Comment: @yasen I can't say I'm surprised, ulong is a typedef BTW, I forgot to take it out when I posted it

Answer (score 1):

Some basic advice, then a basic (albeit untested) answer...

The advice:  If you have one resource that's very limited, take advantage of other resources.  In this case, since time is limited, take up a lot of space.  Don't dynamically allocate any memory, make it all fixed length arrays.

The way I would do it is simply to have one boolean array and apply Aristophanes' sieve to it:

```
void findPrimes(int cap) { // set to void for now, since I don't know your return type
    bool[] possibilities = new bool[cap + 1]; // has to be dynamic so that you can scale for any top
    possibilities[0] = false;
    possibilities[1] = false;
    int found = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i < cap; ) {
        ++found;
        for (int j = i + i; j < cap; j += i) {
            possibilities[j] = false;
        }
        do {
            ++i;
        } while (!possibilities[i]);
    }

    // at this point, found says how many you've found, and everything in possibilities that is true is a factor.  Just return it however you need.
```

I see aaronman beat me to the punch with the sieve idea.  Mine is a slightly different implementation (more exactly resembles the original sieve, using only addition), and uses less dynamic memory, so I'm still submitting it.

Comment: Anyone want to tell me why the -1?

Comment: Wasn't me but you did spell Eratosthenes completely wrong

Comment: @aaronman Blame Google!  :->  If you type in "sieve of ar", it will automatically complete it to "aristophanes" and link to the "sieve of eratosthenes" wiki page.  I just assumed it was an alternate spelling, though apparently it's just a sufficiently common misspelling.  (For what it's worth, I thought I was looking up the Sieve of Archimedes, and it at least corrected me that far...)

Comment: Lol, i highly doubt that was it anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can get quite a nice speedup by preexcluding even numbers, just change your increment to `i += 2` and make sure you don't omit 2 in your result array. You might even think about trying to preexclude multiples of 3, but that starts getting dirty. Something along the lines:

```
for(long i = 1; i < qtd; i += 6) {
    //check if i is prime
    //check if i+4 is prime
}
```

This should be enough to get you below the limit.

Comment: Or you might think about preexcluding multiples of every prime before the one you're considering... but then you would be Eratosthenes.  :-p

Comment: Your code implementation excludes 3 and 19, at the very least.

Comment: Nah, the sieve would mean having to either flag out numbers from a field and always checking the flags, or compacting an array of numbers, which is even slower. I think, his basic approach is good and can easily improved sufficiently.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein It doesn't if you remember to add it to the result array beforehand. 19 = 3*6 + 1, which is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The sieve of Eratosthenes is the right way to do it, as others have suggested. But the implementations I saw here were very complicated. The sieve is extremely easy to implement. E.g.:

```
std::vector<int> get_primes(uint max) {
  std::vector<int> primes;
  std::vector<bool> is_composite(max+1,false);
  for (uint i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
    if (!is_composite[i]) {
      primes.push_back(i);
      for (uint j = i+i; j <= max; j += i) {
        is_composite[j] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return primes;
}
```

Comment: This is fine, but there is no implementation of is_composite

Answer (score 0):

There are two big, technical performance drains in your code:

1. You insert your primes into a vector. Whenever the vector exceeds its allocated size, it will get a new, larger buffer, copy everything over, and delete the old one. `new` is very expensive in terms of performance, even more expensive than the copying involved. You can avoid this by telling the vector to `reserve()` enough space.
2. You use `sqrt()` in your inner loop. This too is a slow function, square the prime instead (takes only one cycle on modern hardware), it will be faster.

Comment: about 1: reallocation and copying happens so few times, that it is totally irrelevant for the final performance (like, milliseconds). Using `reserve()` can still be justified, just saying it will not really help with the slowness here.