# Summation of nth prime

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a program that finds the summation of prime numbers. It must use redirected input. I've written it so that it finds the largest number for the input then uses that as the nth prime. It then uses the nth prime to set the size of the array. It works up until I try to printf the sum. I can't figure out why I'm getting a seg fault there of all place.I think I've allocated the arrays correctly with malloc. why would the fault happen at printf on not when I'm using my arrays? Any suggestions on my code are also welcome.

EDIT
used a test input of 2000 form 1 to 2000 and it worked but the full test file of 10000 form 1 to 10000 crashes still looking into why. I'm guessing I didnt allocate enough space

EDIT
My problem was in my sieve I didnt take the sqrt(nthprime) so it found more primes then the array could hold

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int nprime (int max);
void sieve_sum ( int *primes, int nthprime, int tests,int *input);

int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    int max=0; //largest input
    int tests; //number of tests
    int nthprime; //estimated nth prime
    int *primes; //array of primes
    int *input; // numbers to put in to P(n), where p(n) is the summation of primes

    scanf("%d",&tests); //gets number of tests
    input = malloc(sizeof(int)*tests);

    //test values
    for(i=0; i<=tests-1; i++)
        scanf("%d",&input[i]);

    //finds max test value
    i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < tests; i++ )
    {
        if ( input[i] > max-1 )
            max = input[i];
    }

    // calls nprime places value in n
    nthprime = nprime(max);
    primes = malloc(sizeof(int)*nthprime);

    // calls sieve_sum
    sieve_sum( primes, nthprime, tests, input);

    //free memory
    free(input);
    free(primes);
    return 0;
}

//finds Primes and their sum
void sieve_sum ( int *primes, int nthprime, int tests,int *input)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    //fills in arrays with 1's
    for(i=2; i<=nthprime; i++)
        primes[i] = 1;

    //replaces non primes with 0's
    i=0;
    for(i=2; i<=sqrt(nthprime); i++)
    {
        if(primes[i] == 1)
        {
            for(j=i; (i*j)<=(nthprime); j++)
                   primes[(i*j)] = 0;
        }
    }

    //rewrites array with only primes
    j=1;
    i=0;
    for(i=2; i<=nthprime; i++)
    {
        if(primes[i] == 1)
        {
            primes[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }

    //sums
    i=0;
    for ( i=1; i<=tests; i++ )
    {
        int sum=0;//sum of primes

        j=0;
        for(j=1; j<=input[i-1]; j++)
        {
                sum = primes[j] + sum;
        }

        printf("%d\n", sum );
    }
    return 0;
}

//finds the Nth number prime
int nprime (int max)
{
    //aproximization of pi(n) (the nth prime) times 2 ensures correct allocation of memory
    max = ceil( max*((log (max)) + log ((log (max)))))*2;
    return (max);
}
```

Example input file:

```
20
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Example output should be:

```
2 
5 
10 
17 
28 
41 
58 
77 
100
129
129
100
77
58
41
28
17
10
5
2
```

Comment: this is wrong on a couple of levels - I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debugging info (`gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and use the debugger (`gdb`) once you got no compilation warnings anymore.

Comment: maybe start by reading the manual of malloc: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/ (HINT: malloc expects the number of bytes to allocate as argument. you are probably missing a ` * sizeof(int)`)

Comment: Also, for your nth prime function, choose your variable to be an `int` or a `double` and stick with it. There's implicit casting all over the place.

Comment: Please post the re-directed input you are using.

Comment: here not technically a dupe, but should help get ur answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518927/number-prime-with-c-what-is-wrong-with-the-code-and-how-to-optimize/18519099#18519099

Comment: updated with re-directed input. fixed the variables. still looking for where it goes wrong

Comment: You included 'example output' as a heading — but didn't include any data.  I'm puzzled what you're after, exactly, and what all the input is for.  Is it that you need to find the sum of the first N primes? So for N = 1, the sum S = 2; for N = 2, S = 5; for N = 3, S = 10; for N = 4, S = 17; etc?  What is the purpose of all the numbers after the first in the file?  Is the `nprime()` function returning an approximation to the Nth prime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I'm going to have a shot at this without saying too much because it looks like it might be a homework problem.

My best guess is that a lot of people have shied away from even looking at your code because it's a bit too messy for their level of patience. It's not irredeemable, but you would probably get a better response if it were considerably cleaner.

So, first, a few critical comments on your code to help you clean it up: it is insufficiently well-commented to make your intentions clear at any level, including what the overall purpose of the program is; it is inconsistently indented and spaced in an unconventional manner; and your choice of variable names leaves something to be desired, which is exacerbated by the absence of comments on variable declarations.

You should compile this code with something like (assuming your source file is called `sumprimes.c`):

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -o sumprimes sumprimes.c -lm
```

Have a look at the warnings this produces, and it will alert you to a few, admittedly fairly minor, problems.

The major immediate issue that I can see by inspection is that your program will certainly segfault because the storage that you have allocated with `malloc()` is too small by a factor of `sizeof(int)`, which you have omitted.

A static error-checker like [splint](http://www.splint.org/) would help you detect some further issues; there's no need to slavishly follow all of its recommendations, though: once you *understand* them all, you can decide which ones to follow.

A few other remarks:

- “Magic numbers”, such as 100 in your code, are considered *very* bad form. As a rule of thumb, the only number that should ever appear in code literally is 0 (zero), and then only sometimes. Your 100 would be much better represented as something *named* (like a `const int` or, more traditionally, a `#define`) to give an indication of its meaning.
- It is unconventional to “outdent” variable declarations in the manner done in your code
- If a function is advertised to return a value, you should *always* check it for errors, e.g. make sure that the return value of `malloc()` is not `NULL`, check that the return value of `scanf()` (if you use it) is the expected value, etc.
- As a general matter of style, it is usually considered good practice in *C* to declare variables one per line with a short explanatory comment. There are exceptions, but it's a reasonable rule-of-thumb.
- For any kind of input, `scanf()` is a poor choice because it alters the state of `stdin` in ways that are difficult to predict unless the input is *exactly* as expected, which you can never depend on. If you want to read in an integer, it is much better to read what's available on `stdin` with `fgets()` into a buffer, and then use `strtol()`, as you can do much more effective error-checking and reporting that way.
- It is not recommended to cast the return of `malloc()` any more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I fixed the outdented variables for him — quietly — while fixing up some of the other issues with the question itself.  Good answer.  You might mention checking the return from `scanf()` explicitly – as well as `malloc()`.

Comment: Thank you. Ill fixed alot of what you suggested reupped my code